Most efficient domain definition for nonblank text with no control chars in PostgreSQL
I want to define a domain for text lines with no control characters and no surrounding whitespace.
Also, I want a domain with the same restriction except it would allow embedded new lines with no preceding whitespace (text block with no trailing spaces on any line).
After some experimenting I have two viable solutions for the text-line:
CREATE DOMAIN textline1 AS text
       CHECK ((VALUE = btrim(VALUE)) AND 
         (VALUE !~ '[[:cntrl:]]') AND
         (length(VALUE) > 0));

CREATE DOMAIN textline2 AS text
       CHECK ((VALUE = btrim(VALUE)) AND 
         (VALUE !~ '[^[:print:]]') AND
         (length(VALUE) > 0));

Both work, but I am not sure they are the most efficient. My use case does not include very large tables, so the performance is not critical, but it is still nice to maximize efficiency.
For the second case I tried
CREATE DOMAIN textblock AS text
       CHECK ((VALUE = btrim(VALUE, E' \n')) AND 
         (VALUE !~ E'[[^:print:]\n]') AND
         (VALUE !~ E' \n') AND
         (length(VALUE) > 0));

This works but seems overly complicated, and I am not sure about the efficiency, but as yet not come up with alternate definitions.

The check conditions in the original post are more complicated than necessary:   each domain can be checked with a single regular expression.
The following two domain definitions address the described requirements:
CREATE DOMAIN textline AS TEXT CHECK (VALUE ~ '^(?=\S)[[:print:]\t]*(?<=\S)$');

CREATE DOMAIN textblock AS TEXT CHECK (VALUE ~ '^(?=\S)[[:print:]\n\r\t]*(?<=\S)$');

Each of these uses a single regular expression to validate the value. These expressions should be reasonably efficient. Because they are only performed when values are assigned, optimal efficiency should not be a significant concern other than when performing massive bulk inserts or updates. The only difference between the expressions is that embedded carriage returns and newlines are accepted for textblock but rejected for textline. The checks start with a zero-length look-ahead at the beginning of the value to ensure that the first character doesn't belong to the space class. The next part verifies that the value only contains permitted characters. The last check is a zero-length look-behind at the end of the value to ensure that the last character doesn't belong to the space class.
The regular expression for checking textline was vetted with the following query and results:
WITH
  test_cases (id, label, value, accept) AS (
    VALUES
      (1, 'empty text', '', FALSE),
      (2, 'newline only text', E'\n', FALSE),
      (3, 'space only text', ' ', FALSE),
      (4, 'text with leading whitespace', ' a', FALSE),
      (5, 'text with trailing whitespace', 'a ', FALSE),
      (6, 'control characters', CHR(1), FALSE),
      (7, 'multiline text', E'a\nz', FALSE),
      (8, 'single non-space printable character', 'a', TRUE),
      (9, 'text with no spaces', 'az', TRUE),
      (10, 'text with embedded spaces', 'a z', TRUE),
      (11, 'text with embedded tabs', E'a\tz', TRUE)
  )
SELECT
  id,
  label,
  accept,
  accept IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (value ~ '^(?=\S)[[:print:]\t]*(?<=\S)$') AS passed
FROM
  test_cases;




id
label
accept
passed




1
empty text
false
true


2
newline only text
false
true


3
space only text
false
true


4
text with leading whitespace
false
true


5
text with trailing whitespace
false
true


6
control characters
false
true


7
multiline text
false
true


8
single non-space printable character
true
true


9
text with no spaces
true
true


10
text with embedded spaces
true
true


11
text with embedded tabs
true
true



The same process was used to validate the expression for textblock:
WITH
  test_cases (id, label, value, accept) AS (
    VALUES
      (1, 'empty text', '', FALSE),
      (2, 'newline only text', E'\n', FALSE),
      (3, 'space only text', E' ', FALSE),
      (4, 'text with leading whitespace', ' x', FALSE),
      (5, 'text with trailing whitespace', 'x ', FALSE),
      (6, 'control characters', CHR(1), FALSE),
      (7, 'multiline text', E'a\nz', TRUE),
      (8, 'single non-space printable character', 'a', TRUE),
      (9, 'text with no spaces', 'az', TRUE),
      (10, 'text with embedded spaces', 'a z', TRUE),
      (11, 'text with embedded tabs', E'a\tz', TRUE),
      (12, 'text with embedded carriage returns', E'a\rz', TRUE)
  )
SELECT
  id,
  label,
  accept,
  accept IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (value ~ '^(?=\S)[[:print:]\n\r\t]*(?<=\S)$') AS passed
FROM
  test_cases;




id
label
accept
passed




1
empty text
false
true


2
newline only text
false
true


3
space only text
false
true


4
text with leading whitespace
false
true


5
text with trailing whitespace
false
true


6
control characters
false
true


7
multiline text
true
true


8
single non-space printable character
true
true


9
text with no spaces
true
true


10
text with embedded spaces
true
true


11
text with embedded tabs
true
true


12
text with embedded carriage returns
true
true



